# KeyCloak Docker compose: Disable overwriting of tables

Tags: jhipster, keycloak

I am trying to setup Keycloak using docker compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:9.0.0
    command:
      [
        '-b',
        '0.0.0.0',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=IGNORE_EXISTING',
        '-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000',
        '-Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=1000',
        '-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled'
      ]
    volumes:
      - ./realm-config:/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - DB_VENDOR=MYSQL
      - DB_ADDR=testmysqldb.mysql.database.azure.com
      - DB_USER=testuser
      - DB_PASSWORD=testpassword
      - DB_DATABASE=keycloak
    ports:
      - 9080:9080
      - 9443:9443
      - 10990:10990
```

It takes long time to setup all the tables but eventually tables were created. However, I got timeout for jboss startup after some time. When I try to restart the the container, I get following error:

> ERROR [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.conn.DefaultLiquibaseConnectionProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) Change Set META-INF/jpa-changelog-authz-4.0.0.CR1.xml::authz-4.0.0.CR1::psilva@redhat.com failed. Error: **Table 'resource_server_perm_ticket' already exists** [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE keycloak_new.RESOURCE_SERVER_PERM_TICKET (ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, OWNER VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, REQUESTER VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, CREATED_TIMESTAMP BIGINT NOT NULL, GRANTED_TIMESTAMP BIGINT NULL, RESOURCE_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, SCOPE_ID VARCHAR(36) NULL, RESOURCE_SERVER_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL)]
> 15:08:40,541 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to update database

I am unable to find any solution for how to solve this error. Basically, once tables exist, I expect keycloak NOT to try overwriting them. I am sure I am missing config here. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i solved it by running keycloak in standalone mode. It created the database structure without any timeout issues.
Once database was created, I started keycloak in docker mode and connected to external database. It started without any problem.

Comment: mine was on docker stack. I increased the delay time of keycloak service on docker-stack.yml configuration. Increase delay time on deploy -> update_config -> delay